# select data using 'IN' in MySQL using joins on multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

There are many questions like this but didn't helped me I have multiple tables that contain different data.
There is an institutes table that contains multiple institutes

**institutes**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |

I'm using the id of institutes in the courses table

**courses**

| id | course | inst_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1,2 |
| 2 | B | 1 |

Now i want to select institute name based on **courses.inst_id**, it return **B** when courses.id = 2 that's good but when id = 1 it returns only one institute name but inst_id contains on **1,2** so it should be returned both values **A and B** is there is any way to do that?

Here is my try

```
$match = '1,2';
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT courses.*, teachers.name,i.name as institute FROM courses 
    JOIN teachers ON teachers.id =  courses.teacher_id JOIN institutes i WHERE i.id IN 
    ($match) AND courses.id = :id ");
    $stmt->execute([':id' => $id]);
    return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: You don't use `inst_id` anywhere in your SQL

Comment: Do you actually store the values as comma-separated valeus?

Comment: `$match` should have been parameterized.

Comment: If you have the possibility change your table design , and do not store values as comma-separated

Comment: yeah i am storing data with comma-separated

Answer (score 0):

Save `inst_id` as a string such as `'1','2'`

Check this query

```
SELECT courses.*, teachers.name,i.name as institute 
FROM courses 
JOIN teachers ON teachers.id =  courses.teacher_id JOIN institutes i WHERE i.id IN 
(SELECT data_set.inst_id FROM (select inst_id from courses) AS data_set) AND courses.id = :id
```

Make necessary changes the query where needed.

Comment: Can you please explain this line `(SELECT data_set.inst_id FROM (select inst_id from table_a) AS data_set)`?

Comment: This will return inst_id from courses for `in`

Comment: Wouldn't `select inst_id from courses` do just that on its own? Also, where in that code are you comparing it to the values provided by the user?

Comment: @Dharman Yes, you are right. Need to be updated the query.